# How to create a dot plot with a lot of values in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, histogram, bar-chart

I created a bar chart to show the population distribution of Vietnam. This is my `vietnam2015` data:

```
 Year Age.group Est.pop
1  2015       0-4    7753
2  2015       5-9    7233
3  2015     10-14    6623
4  2015     15-19    6982
5  2015     20-24    8817
6  2015     25-29    8674
7  2015     30-34    7947
8  2015     35-39    7166
9  2015     40-44    6653
10 2015     45-49    6011
11 2015     50-54    5469
12 2015     55-59    4623
13 2015     60-64    3310
14 2015     65-69    1896
15 2015     70-74    1375
16 2015     75-79    1162
17 2015       80+    1878
```

This is my bar chart and I was wondering if I could also make a dot plot instead of a bar chart.

```
Library(tidyverse)

vietnam2015 %>%
  filter(Age.group != "5-9") %>% # Somehow this weird value creeped into the data frame, is therefor filtered out.
  ggplot(aes(x = Age.group, y = Est.pop)) +
  geom_col(colour = "black",
           fill = "#FFEB3B")
```

[image]

Now I know a dot plot is usually for data with not that many data points. But can I create a dot plot where one dot represents 1000 people or a million? I like to communicate better that the bars consist of people. Like flowingdata's example and middle image:

[image: Histogram explained]

Comment: Have you looked at `geom_dotplot()`?

Comment: Yes, but I can't seem to find the right number of binwidth. I get an error: `stat_bindot() using bins = 30. Pick better value with binwidth.` Also `geom_dotplot` documentation says `...and dots are stacked, with each dot representing one observation`.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `geom_dotplot`. As you mentioned, dot plot is usually for small count number, but we can aggregate the data. In the following code, I used `mutate(Est.pop = round(Est.pop, digits = -3)/1000)` to round the `Est.pop` to thousand and then divided by 1000. After that, I repeat each `Age.group` for how many times I just calculated in the `Est.pop` column. Finally, I used the `geom_dotplot` to plot the data. Each dot represents 1000 people. y-axis is hidden because I think this visualization mainly focuses on the dot number.

```
# Load package
library(tidyverse)

# Process the data
dt2 <- dt %>%
  mutate(Est.pop = round(Est.pop, digits = -3)/1000) %>%
  split(f = .$Age.group) %>%
  map_df(function(x) x[rep(row.names(x), x$Est.pop[1]), ])

# Plot the data
ggplot(dt2, aes(x = Age.group)) +
  geom_dotplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(NULL, breaks = NULL)
```

[image]

Data

```
dt <- read.table(text = " Year Age.group Est.pop
1  2015       0-4    7753
                 2  2015       5-9    7233
                 3  2015     10-14    6623
                 4  2015     15-19    6982
                 5  2015     20-24    8817
                 6  2015     25-29    8674
                 7  2015     30-34    7947
                 8  2015     35-39    7166
                 9  2015     40-44    6653
                 10 2015     45-49    6011
                 11 2015     50-54    5469
                 12 2015     55-59    4623
                 13 2015     60-64    3310
                 14 2015     65-69    1896
                 15 2015     70-74    1375
                 16 2015     75-79    1162
                 17 2015       80+    1878 ",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can generate values from zero upto the `Est.pop` for each `Age.group` and plot. But I'm sure there is other better ways.

```
library(reshape2)

df2 = dcast(data = df, Year~Age.group, value.var = "Est.pop")

df3 = do.call(rbind, lapply(2:NCOL(df2), function(i)
data.frame(Age.group = names(df2)[i], Est.pop = seq(0, df2[,i], 200))))

ggplot(data = df3[df3$Age.group != "5-9",],
   aes(x = factor(Age.group), y = Est.pop)) +
geom_point()
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
df = structure(list(Year = c(2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L), Age.group = c("0-4", "5-9", "10-14", "15-19", 
"20-24", "25-29", "30-34", "35-39", "40-44", "45-49", "50-54", 
"55-59", "60-64", "65-69", "70-74", "75-79", "80+"), Est.pop = c(7753L, 
7233L, 6623L, 6982L, 8817L, 8674L, 7947L, 7166L, 6653L, 6011L, 
5469L, 4623L, 3310L, 1896L, 1375L, 1162L, 1878L)), .Names = c("Year", 
"Age.group", "Est.pop"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but It's not really what I had in mind. Maybe there's a way we can plot a couple of rows of dots thick for each individual `Age.group` ....? I'm now thinking of a detour, maybe the `library(waffle)` package can help us.